# iterate through list in StringTemplate

Tags: java, stringtemplate

I have a map in Java

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
```

Each (key,value) pair of this map is a list of urls:

```
List<String> thumbnailImgUrl = new ArrayList<>();
for (....) {
    thumbnailUrl.add(url);
}
model.put("photoUrl", thumbnailImgUrl);
```

I am passing the object "model" to the StringTemplate.

How can I access individual urls in string template?

```
Notification(model) ::= <<
  {how can I access the individual urls here?}
>>
```

Comment: `List<String> urls = (List<String>)(model.get("photoUrl"));`

Comment: what @LuiggiMendoza suggested is theoretically correct, assuming that you always have key-value pairs of type `String,List<String>`. If that is not the case, you will get an exception (casting will fail). If your map indeed always have such key-value pairs, consider creating it like this `Map<String, List<String>> model = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: @Anton you won't get an exception, you will get a compiler warning. The only way OP could get a `ClassCastException` is if he/she stores something different than a `List<String>` in `model` using `"photoUrl"` as key.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that's what I meant to write, my bad. But still, converting the map to `Map<String, List<String>>` would make life much more easier. Though I fear the OP uses the map for all kind of object types. I personally see `Object` as a last resort but that's a different topic

Comment: @Anton we don't know if indeed there are `String`, `Integer` or other kind of data in `model`. This `model` object seems like a small `HttpSession.setAttributes(String, Object)` for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I iterate though a java list in stringtemplate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437005/how-do-i-iterate-though-a-java-list-in-stringtemplate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already flagged this question as a duplicate, but just to prevent any more comments or answers that discuss how to cast or iterate in Java, the correct StringTemplate template that answers the question is

```
Notification(model) ::= <<
    <model.photoUrl:{v | model.photoUrl[<i>]=<v> }>
>>
```

The `map.key` accesses the item in a map and the `<list:{v|<v>}>` part iterates over a list and applies an anonimous sub-template to each element of the list.

Comment: I am trying to put these in a html block like this

<model.photoUrl:{v | <img src="<v>"></img>}>

but it's not working. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: You need to use some other characters as ST delimiters instead of '<' and '>'. The ['$' char is usually used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490351/stringtemplate-remove-as-delimiters?lq=1) when mixing ST and HTML. [Another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146113/how-to-get-stringtemplate-v4-to-ignore-as-delimiter) of using ST and HTML together.

Comment: You can also define ST delimiters directly in the group file by using `delimiters "$", "$"` [directive](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST4/Group+file+syntax).

Comment: I found this site [cheat sheet](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST4/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet) very useful for understanding stringTemplate.

Hope fully it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this,
You have to use a loop and a temporary variable in the following way:

```
Notification(model) ::= <<
$model.thumbnailImgUrl: {thumbnailImgUrl | URL is :- $thumbnailImgUrl.url$}$
>>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Get the Object and cast it to your class type-

```
List<String> urls = (List<String>)(model.get("photoUrl"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this work for me

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : model.entrySet()) {
        ArrayList<String> urlLst= (ArrayList<String>) entry.getValue();
        for(String url:urlLst)
            System.out.println(url);
}
```